# Write a Scala Function to find the most shared word between Two Files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need a function that will receive two files as inputs and output the most shared word between the two files.

For example:
File1 = thank thank thank you you
File2 = thank you you you

The output would be 'you' since it's shared 2 times. My current function:

```
def sharedWord(a:String,b:String) : String ={
val aFile = sc.textFile(a);
val bFile = sc.textFile(b);
val flattenMapa = aFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));
val flattenMapb = bFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));
val mapreduceA = flattenMapa.map(word => (word.toLowerCase, 1)).reduceByKey((key,value) => key+value);
val mapreduceB = flattenMapb.map(word => (word.toLowerCase, 1)).reduceByKey((key,value) => key+value);
//not sure how to compare the two mapreduce collections of words
//val common = most shared word.
return common
}
```

I'm stuck with how to properly compare the two map-reduce key-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the missing piece.

```
// mapreduceA: RDD of [(thank, 3), (you, 2)]
// mapreduceB: RDD of [(thank, 1), (you, 3)]

val joinedRDD = mapreduceA.join(mapreduceB)                                 // (1)
// RDD of ((thank,(3,1)), (you,(2,3)))

val minimumWordFrequencies = joinedRDD.mapValues(x => List(x._1, x._2).min) // (2)
// RDD of ((thank,1), (you,2))

val mostFrequentWord =
    minimumWordFrequencies.reduce((a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b)      // (3)
// mostFrequentWord: (you,2)

val common = mostFrequentWord._1
```

1. join two PairRDD by key (word).
2. apply function to select the minimum number of word frequency.
3. selet the most frequent word.